# SQL Setting Constraints In where clause, not sure what to do

Tags: sql, t-sql, if-statement, where-clause

I have another question in regards to constraints in the where clause. Here is my code:

```
use db.random123
go
create view dbo.increasebasedonvar
as
select *
from dbo.incbasedondate as ibd
where ibd.[avg rent var] < 30 and 
    ([avg rent var] between 15 and 30 and datediff(month,ibd.leasedate, '2016-09-01') > 24)
go
```

My goal here is to exclude records where the [avg rent var] is >= 30 and exclude a subset of records if the [avg rent var] is between (inclusive) 15 and 30 and the time between the 'leasedate' and a future date is less than 24 months. Then I would like to return all of the remaining records that are not excluded by these parameters.

Unfortunately I am not completely sure how to achieve this I tried putting together an if statement but that didn't seem to work appropriately. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT------------------------------------------

So I decided to try and go a different route by creating a helper column in the select query. This is what I have now.

```
use Random
go
create view dbo.incbasedondate
as
select 
    riv.unitcode,
    riv.lcode,
    riv.sitename,
    riv.ledgerid,
    riv.unitname,
    riv.tenantid,
    riv.sfname,
    riv.slname,
    riv.scompany,
    riv.stdrate,
    riv.rent,
    riv.[std rate variance],
    riv.[average rent],
    riv.[avg rent var],
    **case 
        when riv.[avg rent var] not between 15 and 30
        then 1
        else
            case
                when (riv.[avg rent var] between 15 and 30) and datediff(month,riv.leasedate, '2016-09-01') > 24
                then '15-30 inc'
                else null
            end 
        end as [15-30 Increase],**
    riv.leasedate,
    riv.rentlastchanged,
    riv.[Days Same],
    riv.[Days Same Form],
    riv.paidthrudate,
    riv.schedrent,
    riv.schedrentstart,
    riv.tenzip,
    riv.sitezip
from dbo.rentincreaseview as riv
where 
    ([days same form] <= 9 and
    datediff(month, leasedate,'2016-09-01') >= 8)
    or([days same form] >9 and
    datediff(month, rentlastchanged,'2016-09-01') >= 12)
go

drop view dbo.FinalIncDataSet
use Random
go
create view dbo.FinalIncDataSet
as
**select *
from dbo.incbasedondate as ibd
where ibd.[avg rent var] < 30 and ibd.[15-30 Increase] is not null
order by ibd.unitcode**

go
```

These being the key parts for this problem:

```
case 
            when riv.[avg rent var] not between 15 and 30
            then 1
            else
                case
                    when (riv.[avg rent var] between 15 and 30) and datediff(month,riv.leasedate, '2016-09-01') > 24
                    then '15-30 inc'
                    else null
                end 
            end as [15-30 Increase],**


**select *
    from dbo.incbasedondate as ibd
    where ibd.[avg rent var] < 30 and ibd.[15-30 Increase] is not null
    order by ibd.unitcode**
```

And now my results are even more wrong, it looks like nearly everything is being eliminated. Is there a problem with my nested case when statement?

Answer (score 0):

Your exclusion criteria is - exclude records where the [avg rent var] is >= 30 and exclude a subset of records if the [avg rent var] is between (inclusive) 15 and 30 and the time between the 'leasedate' and a future date is less than 24 months.

Wouldn't this part of the query end up including records that you are trying to exclude ?

```
([avg rent var] between 15 and 30 and ...)
```

How about changing the where condition as follows -

```
where ibd.[avg rent var] < 30 or 
    not ([avg rent var] between 15 and 30 and datediff(month,ibd.leasedate, '2016-09-01') < 24)
```

It does seem a little convoluted, but we are looking at two distinct sets matching the exclusion criteria here. Hope this helps.

Comment: In theory I was trying to create an IF statement that would exclude records where the [avg rent var] is between 15 and 30 if the time between the lease date and future date is less than 24 months. But it looks like I may have done the opposite. I'm hung up on the correct syntax to use.

Comment: If I change that to not, won't that exclude all records between 15 and 30? I want to include the records between 15 and 30 as long as the time difference is greater than 24 months.

Comment: i just revised my response based on your previous comment. You can change your code accordingly and check it out.